# How do I use jquery to achieve hover effect on a link that is normally done with css :hover to change the link's color

Tags: jquery, hover

How do I use jquery to achieve hover effect on a link that is normally down with css :hover,  so when I hover over a link it changes to a different color, and when my mouse leaves the link it returns to the color it had before?

**Edit**
My link has an inline style that sets its color, so I tried add and remove class they don't work, it seems the newly added css class cannot override the inline style.

Comment: what got this working is griegs comment on adding "!important" to the added css class, then the override happened.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

```
$("#linkname").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).addClass("highlight");
});

$("#linkname").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).removeClass("highlight");
});
```

mouseover, mouseout will also work.

for the link you can use the id with the # or class name with the .

so

so you can then use;

```
$("#anchorid").mouseleave(
```

or

```
$(".anchorclass").mouseleave(
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  I forgot to mention my link has an inline style that sets its color, so I tried add and remove class they don't work, it seems the newly added css class cannot override the inline style.

Comment: use removeAttr() for inline styles

Comment: or use .css( propertyName, value  ).  that would be better than removeAttr()

Comment: so much code for so little, why not just use the [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function?

Comment: @ali, yeah could do and is probably a better fit.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way just use [`jQuery.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$('a#mylink').hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass("underline");},function(){$(this).toggleClass("underline");});
```

or

```
$('a#mylink').hover(function(){$(this).css("text-decoration","underline");},function(){$(this).css("text-decoration","none");});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. By using text-decoration it works, but I prefer the color change which has me stuck because I have an inline style that sets its color, which jquery added css class cannot seem to override

Comment: @ray247 use a class name and in the class style set "color: red !important".  So then use the first line in this answer to add and remove the class.

Comment: Its not recommended but you could use the !important directive to force overriding. If you do use !important keep in mind nothing will override this. If you are okay with inline css then just added color as ray recommended.

Comment: One last thing since I think ray247 may benefit from it. `!important` is discouraged because it breaks inheritance in css.

Css gives greater importance to more completely defined paths so you can also use that to override example `div#outterwrapper div.links a {}` will override a style which is simply `div.links a {}` or `a {}`. Also the order in which the style elements (and even style sheets) appear dictate overriding. Firebug can be very useful in figuring whats overriding what. Hierarchy is stylesheet 3rd, in-page style 2nd, in-line 1st, `!important` overrides all.